# Parse Dashboard shows some swirling colored dots and then goes blank

Tags: parse-platform, parse-dashboard

When I enter the URL for the Parse Dashboard in the browser, https://www.example.com/dashboard, I see the dashboard login page. I enter my credentials and the URL changes to https://www.example.com/dashboard/apps. After a few seconds, the URL changes again to https://www.example.com/dashboard/apps//browser and three swirling colored dots (pink, green and blue) appear for about 12 seconds and then the screen goes blank. I tried to set the VERBOSE environment variable (which works on the Parse Server) to get more detailed logging, but that doesn't work with the dashboard.

Here is my Parse-Dashboard/parse-dashboard-config.json file:

```
    {
      "apps": [{
      "serverURL": "http://localhost:1337/parse",
      "appId": "<my app id>",
      "masterKey": "<my key>",
      "iconName": "",
      "primaryBackgroundColor": "",
      "secondaryBackgroundColor": ""
      }],

      "users": [
        {
          "user": "<user1>",
          "pass": "<pass>"
        },
        {
          "user": "<user2>",
          "pass": "<pass>"
        }
      ],
      "iconsFolder": "icons",
      "useEncryptedPasswords": false
    }
```

The command lines that I use to start up the Parse Dashboard are:

```
    su -l parse
    cd git/parse-dashboard
    bin/parse-dashboard --config Parse-Dashboard/parse-dashboard-config.json --mountPath "/dashboard"
```

A second, and related, question is how do I turn on logging/debugging in the Parse Dashboard? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: The third link is wrong. It is currently:
`https://www.example.com/dashboard/apps//browser`
and it should be:
`https://www.example.com/dashboard/apps/<my app id>/browser`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using parse-dashboard --config parse-dashboard-config.json
then put the parse-dashboard-config.json  in the root.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I fixed it by changing:

```
serverURL: "http://localhost:1337/parse"
```

to

```
serverURL": "http://{YourHostIp}:1337/parse"
```